# HTTPS and Zend Framework

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, ssl

I am trying to convert a functional ZF application to use SSL. The certificate is valid and works, but I am having trouble configuring the application.

Here's what's in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

IndexController is really simple:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction() {
      $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
      if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'dash');
      } else {
        $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'auth');
      }
    }

}
```

When I browse to the site without specifying https or port, it accurately routes me to https://app-url.com, but then tries to redirect to https://app-url.com/auth and returns a 403. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 'index' is the name for the controller and 'dash' the name for the action, your parameters for the [Redirector Helper](http://framework.zend.com/code/filedetails.php?repname=Zend%20Framework&path=/tags/release-1.11.12/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/Redirector.php)<sup>1</sup> are in the wrong order.

The first parameter is the action, the second the controller. So the correct method call would be

```
$this->_helper->redirector('dash', 'index');
```

This will redirect you to the URL /index/dash if no particular routes are set.

In the case that 'dash' is indeed the name of the controller and 'index' the name of the action, simply add a new controller named `DashController` which contains an `indexAction()` method and the redirect should work.

<sub>1) If you call the helper via $this->_helper->name this will call the direct() method, which in the redirector helper calls the method `gotoSimple($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = array())`</sub>

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified: these redirectors work fine until I add HTTPS rewrites to .htaccess. So it is, in fact, DashController and AuthController that get called there - they do exist, and the redirect works OK until I turn on SSL.

Comment: Ah ok. Does calling sites in HTTPS work in general or do you always run into that 403 error? Maybe you have different directory settings in Apache for HTTPS and HTTP? I tried your code on a local testing environment and it worked flawlessly.